# Переход от UICollectionView к UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: создал в коде `UICollectionView` из картинок, хочу при нажатии на изображение открывать новый `UIViewController`, использовать  `self.present(recipeDetailTVC, animated: true, completion: nil)` в `UICollectionView` не получается.

Пробовал делегатом в этом же классе `var delegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate?`

> protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate {
>       func showDetail() }
>
> class GalleryCollectionView: UICollectionView,
>   UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,
>   UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
>
> var delegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate? - ошибка ниже

пишет:

> Property 'delegate' with type 'CollectionViewCellDelegate?' cannot
>   override a property with type 'UICollectionViewDelegate?'

[image: скриншот работы приложения]

Подскажите, как правильно такое реализовывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор Вам пишет, что свойство `delegate` уже есть у `UICollectionView`. Следовательно, Вам надо использовать другое имя, например `cellDelegate`:

```
class GalleryCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    weak var cellDelegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate?
}
```

Обратите внимание, что свойство `cellDelegate` объявлено с модификатором `weak`. Это поможет Вам избежать утечек памяти. Кроме того, свойство `UICollectionView.delegate` тоже объявлено с модификатором `weak`. Скорее всего, для того, чтобы избежать ошибок при компиляции, Вам придётся изменить и `CollectionViewCellDelegate`:

```
protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate: AnyObject { func showDetail() }
```